# Scipy optimize curve_fit not responding properly

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, exponential, data-fitting

```py
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.linspace(0,11,12)
y_data = np.array([0.02471114, 0.02057292, 0.01752668, 0.01494543, 0.01273249, 0.0110999 , 0.00946524, 0.00805622, 0.00670716, 0.00558925, 0.00465331, 0.00387775])

def func(x,a,b):
    return ((a-1)*(-b*x - (0.024711**(1-a)/(1-a))))**(1/(1-a))
popt,pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x_data, y_data, p0=[1.1,0.1])

a_opt, b_opt = popt
x_model = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(y_data), 100)
y_model = func(x_model, a_opt, b_opt) 
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.plot(x_model, y_model, color='r')
plt.show()
```

This returns a tiny horizontal line at the coordinates of the first datapoint. What am I doing wrong? I am also getting an OptimizeWarning:
Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated error.

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I have updated the question so that there is actually some content now, I would appreciate a little push in the right direction :)

Comment: Try with proper starting parameters: `[1.1, -0.1]`. If that feels incorrect (e.g., because b is negative), carefully check your equation, as there are many parentheses that you can mix up (split it into parts and temporary variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is in `x_model = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(y_data), 100)` which I guess should really be `x_model = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 100)`.

Also, as noted in the comment by @9769953 you should use an initial guess of [1.1, -0.1].

With these changes, the fit looks ok to me.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated. I did manage to figure this out myself in the end, after randomly trying to change all parameters until things started to happen